# how to set yellow and white brightness to the Image using jQuery/Ajax?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, brightness

I am trying to develop a simple page where i can change image brightness. I want yellow and white light effect on image according to scroller with step value.

here is my scroller code:

```
<input type="range" value="0.5" step="0.01" max="1" min="0" name="imp_bright_range">
```

here is my image code:

```
 <div><img src="myimage.jpg" /></div>
```

i am referring these examples http://pixastic.com/lib/docs/#how and http://mezzoblue.github.io/PaintbrushJS/demo/index.html but not successful.

what script example i should refer ?

Comment: var img = new Image();
img.onload = function() {
 Pixastic.process(img, "glow", {amount:0.5,radius:1.0});
}
document.body.appendChild(img);
img.src = "myimage.jpg";

Comment: @MDeSchaepmeester http://pixastic.com/lib/docs/actions/glow/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must vote me up, because i edited the demo more than 1 hour.

Here's js code:

```
$(function() {
    var isPressed = false;
    var pic = $('.pic');
    var scroller = $('.scroller');
    var scroller_container = $('.scroller-container');
    var scroller_container_offset_x = scroller_container.offset().left;

    scroller.mousedown(function() {
        isPressed = true;
    });
    $(document).mouseup(function() {
        isPressed = false;
    });
    $(document).mousemove(function(e) {
        if(!isPressed) return;
        var left_boundary = scroller_container_offset_x;
        var right_boundary = scroller_container_offset_x + 300 - 20;
        var current_scroller_x = scroller.offset().left;
        var point_x = e.clientX;
        var current_sepia = ((current_scroller_x - left_boundary) / 280).toFixed(1);
        console.log('scroller_x:' + current_scroller_x);
        console.log('left_boundary:' + left_boundary);

        if(current_scroller_x >= left_boundary && current_scroller_x <= right_boundary && point_x > left_boundary && point_x < right_boundary) {
            scroller.css('left', point_x);
            console.log(e.clientX + '|' + e.clientY);
        }
        if(point_x <= left_boundary){
            scroller.css('left', left_boundary);
        }
        if(point_x >= right_boundary){
            scroller.css('left', right_boundary);
        }
        pic.css({
            '-webkit-filter': 'sepia('+current_sepia+')',
            'filter': 'sepia('+current_sepia+')'
        });
    });
});
```

Here is a demo, I hope it is helpful to you :).

[scroller-filter-demo](http://codepen.io/abruzzi/pen/oJzmA)